# Can this "assignment in conditional expression" be removed without changing behavior?

Tags: c#, refactoring, resharper, equality, assignment-operator

Refactoring a legacy app, Resharper flagged this very odd code:

```
if( retVal = Util.NetSendCommand( returnedCommands.command ) )
```

The "retVal = " part is grayed out; so I assume I can just remove it. Perhaps what the person who wrote the code meant was an equality test, but it is working as intended as-is, so I can safely just remove that "retVal =" correct?

### UPDATE

Here's the code in context:

```
public bool PendingCommandsExecute_CCRCOMMAND()
{
    bool    retVal      = false;            
    string  theMessage  = new string( '\x00', 1023 );
    string  command     = "CCRCOMMAND";

    try
    {
        if (returnedCommands.key != command) return false;

        HashResultsAdd(command, "Started");

        if( retVal = Util.NetSendCommand( returnedCommands.command ) )
        {
            Util.ReadFinishedChanged 
                += new Util.ReadFinishedHandler( ReadFinished_HHTCOMMAND );
        }
        else            
        {
            return false;
            //                  CommandFailed
            //                  ( command
            //                  , ": Could not complete server handshaking \n"
            //                  + "FAILURE - CCRCOMMAND!" 
            //                  );
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        PDAClient.NRBQ.ExceptionHandler(ex, "PendingCommands.PendingCommandsExecute.HHTCommand");
        return false;
    }                       
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Well it depends - does nothing else ever read the value? I would *hope* that's what the fact that it's greyed out means, but we can't tell without seeing the rest of the code.

Comment: retVal has to be a boolean for that expression to work. You're the only one that can see the code. Does anything after that expression use that variable? If so, removing it will certainly change behavior.

Comment: It is very unlikely you can remove it. Given the variable name, it is probably being returned later on and removing this assignment will break anything using that return value.

Comment: If a value is assigned to and never read even the compiler can tell you that there's no need for it (hence the compiler warning).  Why do you need to be asking us this?

Comment: There is a typo in the code but I guess that is not relevant here.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't remove it. It is calling that method, it just doesn't use the value it returns.

Comment: I'm not talking about removing the whole thing, just the "retVal = " part.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon yes that should be fine, because it is local variable defined at the beginning of the code you posted so nothing else is accessing it.

Answer (score 1):

If you remove it and also remove the declaration of retVal, then the compiler will complain if retVal is used elsewhere.  If the compiler doesn't complain then you should be OK.

It could be that the original developer wanted to be able to view the return value while debugging.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon No, it can be whatever you assign to it.  We can't possibly know what that method will return.

Comment: Right, I mean up to that point; otherwise, he could just look at whether the call to the function returned true or false. At any rate, we have never been able to step through this code, so I think it was just a mistake on his part.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon, please don't take this the wrong way, but in reading some of your recent questions and comments, I can only think you really do not understand some of the code and concepts you are attempting to implement and refactor. I worry about the quality of your work here. If you haven't already, please strongly consider getting deeper into resources that will help you have a better understanding of programming with C#.

Comment: I definitely do not understand this code base; it's a mess. Or at least, it's implemented 180 degrees differently from how I would have done it.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon, in that case, you might find Michael Feathers' book "Working Effectively With Legacy Code" to be helpful. One of the more salient points is having tests in place, and *getting* tests in place. If you're refactoring code without having tests and without understanding it, it will be incredibly difficult to have confidence you're not breaking working code.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: Boy Howdy! Whenever I check anything in, I feel like a cat in a roomful of rocking chairs.